# JS: Trying to Store User Input in Global Variable

Tags: javascript, forms, input, global

I have an input form that asks a user to enter their name. I have an event listener that listens if the form has been submitted. I am able to access the input the user enters from within a function but after many attempts I have been unable to get the user input to be stored in a global variable.

My most recent attempt involves using JS to create a p tag and then inserting the user input between the tags in the hope that I can later access the information between the p tags. This is not working either.

I do not understand why I am able to get content from various elements but am struggling so much to access and store user input. I would really appreciate any help.

Below is my most recent attempt:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form id = "myForm">                
    <input type="text" id = "personName"><br>
    <button id = "nameSubmit">Submit</button>
    </form>

    <div id = "fdiv">
    </div>

    <script>
    myForm.addEventListener("submit", storeName);
    function storeName() {
    var temp = document.forms["myForm"].querySelector('input[type = "text"]').value;

    var para = document.createElement("p");
    para.textContent = temp;
    document.getElementById("fdiv").appendChild(para);

    }

    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: I have used the suggestions offered and my script now works in that I can get the name inserted between the p tags. I have also managed to store the entire element as follows:

username = document.getElementById("fdiv").appendChild(para);

I am really happy that the content of this variable shows up in the console. It appears to me to be a global variable (I had declared it before the function in my modified JS). I am now trying to convert the variable username to string so I can extract only the person's name. However, String(username) is returning a null value. How do I fix this?

Comment: I have modified the one line of JS to read:

username = document.getElementById("fdiv").appendChild(para).innerHTML;

This gets me the person's name. When I type username in the log, it shows up correctly as if it was a global variable. However, when I copy username into a different variable outside the function, that function is shown as having a null value. Can anyone explain this contradiction?

Answer (score 0):

Basically the problem that you are facing is that your global is being wiped out because the action 'submit', forces a reload on the page. If in the eventListenerFunction you instead have

```
function storeName(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
var temp = document.forms["myForm"].querySelector('input[type = "text"]').value;

var para = document.createElement("p");
para.textContent = temp;
document.getElementById("fdiv").appendChild(para);

}
```

The problem of reloading would be solved because you are preventing the default behaviour of this event

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form id = "myForm">
    <input type="text" id = "personName"><br>
    <button id = "nameSubmit">Submit</button>
    </form>

    <div id = "fdiv">
    </div>

    <script>
    console.log('reloaded');
    myForm.addEventListener("submit", storeName);
    function storeName(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
    var temp = document.forms["myForm"].querySelector('input[type = "text"]').value;

    var para = document.createElement("p");
    para.textContent = temp;
    document.getElementById("fdiv").appendChild(para);

    }

    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

It will work because you are not reloading the page (I put a log so you can see that before it was reloading but now, it doesnt and the value gets save)

Comment: You could always declare something in the global scope (for example a constant outside functions / classes / ...) as you propose. But maybe to expose information in the global variables is not the best practice. Check how can you keep states out of forms or other kind of architecture that could help you

Answer (score 0):

Your want to execute the script when you submit the form, but your browser already has a default action for this event, that is a refresh of the page.

To prevent your browser to refresh the page, you can use the `preventDefault()` method. Change the first lines of your function like this:

```
function storeName(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you debug this, you will see that it is in fact working. Go through it line for line in a debugger and you'll see the p tag appears below your submit button. The problem is it doesn't stay there. You need to add a `return false` in your form like so:

```
<form id = "myForm" onsubmit="return false">
```